# Suggestion for dragster/dropzone like dock menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, dock

I'd like to create a dragster/dropzone like dock menu. Looks a bit like a stack with a nsview in it.

After a lot if documentation searching and googling I've found a way to determine a dock icon's location. 
(http://cocoadev.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=1431)

Is nzbdrop creating a view which just looks like an stack to display it's menu or is there a better way of creating this?

Additional info:
I'm not looking for the drop like functionality just the nice way the DropBox window is displayed as an bubble/stack menu on top of it's app icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting to create something similar;
Matt Gemmell created a nice solution for this called MAAttachedWindow:

http://mattgemmell.com/source

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure I understand your question but the Dragster and Dropzone apps clearly work something like this:

1. They have an application icon in the dock.
2. They respond to a drop request in the standard fashion.
3. Upon receiving a drop request, they open an application window above the dock which also accepts a drop request.
4. According to the link you provided, they use the accessibility API to locate their dock icon so they can open the application window above the dock icon.

The window is just a standard application window although most likely modal and floating (like a help window.) It can have any appearance you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am not talking about the functionality but the great way they seem to fake a stack like ui when clicking to the dick icon. I was hoping for some technical tips how others would create the stack like ui which is really nice. Hoping in a smarter way then using a heavily customer window which I need to replace to the dick icon location.

Comment: Something like http://www.ambrosiasw.com/assets/images/galleries_products/dragster/drag_drop_done01.jpg

http://www.appscout.com/images/DropZone_Destinations.jpg

Comment: The window content itself is mostly likely a NSTableview with all the controls hidden. Each row is a cell that shows an icon in an image view and a text label description.

Comment: Was hoping for more info on the window itself.
Ahh well, seems it's all manual work like the black background, the balloon like tip to the icon and semi transparent border and background and rounded edges. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: That's not how they work. There's no step 2, the drop request, they (somehow) detect and popup their menu still inside the drag operation.